# List instructions to fix wrong IDA analysis

Tags: ida, disassembly, x86

I don't want to get too much into detail, but a disastrous chain of events that began with a boolean of incorrect size forced the IDA analyzer to discard a lot of instruction sections of many functions.

Here is what I mean:
[image]

I'm slowly fixing everything up and so there is no problem with that. My question is: **Is there a way to list every instruction not inside of a function in IDA?** Just so I don't leave some of them without a fix.

Comment: As a side-note: if you are a customer I'm fairly certain that Hex-Rays will be interested in what it was that threw off their auto-analysis. I'm not sure if they'd even care if you are within active maintenance for that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I found how to do it. In <kbd>Search</kbd> > <kbd>Not Function</kbd>.